# How to reset CSS ::after style only for last element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using `:after` and `:before` CSS on my event. I have a button called timeline. when I click on timeline button it adds an event and using `:after` I connect this event that looks nice but I want to remove the last event after effect.

Here I paste my code that works properly I am adding an image that shows you what's going wrong.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
div[type="timeline"]>section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

div[type="timeline"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -55px;
  width: .2rem;
  background: grey;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(16px, 23px);
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section>article {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px);
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div type='timeline' id='slide'>
  <section>
    <header>Title One</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Two</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Three</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Four</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:last-of-type`, `:last-child`, `:nth-last-of-type(1)` or `:nth-last-child(1)` to target the last `section` and reset pseudo element in it:

```
div[type="timeline"]>section:last-of-type::after {
  display: none;
}
```

Or use `:not()` selector to filter out the last `section` directly:

```
div[type="timeline"]>section:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a :last child selector.
This will target the last child of any parent in css.

Answer (score 2):

```
div[type="timeline"]>section:last-child::after {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This CSS rule will do what you want:

```
div[type="timeline"]>section:last-child::after  {
   height: 0;
}
```

It selects the `:after` pseudo-element which is attached to the last `section` element and sets its height to 0, making it invisible that way.

INstead of setting the height to 0 you could as well use other properties/settings which make that element invisible.

```css
div[type="timeline"] > section  {
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: 0.5;
        border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
        border-top: 1px solid grey;
        min-height:250px;
        background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 55px;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s
        -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
        -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
        animation: fadein 2s;
    }

    div[type="timeline"] > section:hover {
        opacity:1;
    } 
    
    div[type="timeline"]::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        width: .2rem;
        background: white;
        height: 55px;
    }
    
    div[type="timeline"]>section::after  {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: -55px;
        width: .2rem;
        background: grey;
        height: 55px;
    }
    div[type="timeline"]>section:last-child::after  {
       height: 0;
    }
 
   div[type="timeline"] > section> header  {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: cadetblue;
        transform: translate(16px, 23px);
        font-size: 34px;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
    }
   div[type="timeline"] > section> article {
        transform: translate(12px,14px);
        color: black;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

```html
<div type='timeline' id='slide'>
 <section>
  <header>Title One</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section>
  <header>Title Two</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section>
  <header>Title Three</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section>
  <header>Title Four</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `div[type="timeline"]>section::after{}` to `div[type="timeline"]>section:not(:last-child)::after{}`

```css
div[type="timeline"]>section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

div[type="timeline"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -55px;
  width: .2rem;
  background: grey;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(16px, 23px);
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section>article {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px);
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div type='timeline' id='slide'>
  <section>
    <header>Title One</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Two</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Three</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>Title Four</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another clean solution would be to just add `ID`s to each section, then exclude section #four with the `CSS` `:not` selector.

Hope this helps!

```css
div[type="timeline"]>section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

div[type="timeline"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:not(#four):after   {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -55px;
  width: .2rem;
  background: grey;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(16px, 23px);
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section>article {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px);
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div type='timeline' id='slide'>
  <section id="one">
    <header>Title One</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section id="two">
    <header>Title Two</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section id="three">
    <header>Title Three</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
  <section id="four">
    <header>Title Four</header>
    <article>Content</article>
  </section>
</div>
```